# Url and HTML inspect gives different outcomes with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I copy the url of a facebook page and create a BeautifulSoup object, it gives me a text that is not actually the posts on the pages. Namely

```
text = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/toyota').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
soup.get_text()
```

returns '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nToyota USA - Ana Sayfa\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'.

However, when I inspect that Facebook page and copy HTML element and follow similar steps, I get what I want. So

```
html_inspected = Copied HTML Element
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_inspected)
soup.get_text()
```

returns the actual text on the Facebook page I want. My question is am I supposed to inspect and copy the HTML every time I want to get the actual content in a page? Isn't there any shortcut for getting posts and comments on a Facebook page without inspecting every time?

Comment: Check your `soup` if you find expected elements - website deals with `javascript` so you should not find any rendered information.

Comment: First be aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. The short cut is to use Facebook API which is the allowed way to get data from Facebook

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @HedgeHog, this could be a JavaScript  issue.

The simplest solution would be to use a ready-made [scraper library](https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/) for the task:

```py
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

for post in get_posts('toyota', pages=1):
    print(post['text'][:50])
```

---

Alternatively, you could use Selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

with Firefox() as driver:
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/toyota')
    elem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@dir="auto"]')

    for item in elem:
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: Are you really sure? Could it not be that there is no other content delivered, cause website deals with `javascript`?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly possible.

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm aware of facebook_scraper, but the problem with that library is that it scrapes posts from the latest to the older ones. So, when I want to extract information about posts between 2010 and 2020,  facebook_scraper starts scraping from 2022 regardless, and then it automatically stops scraping for some reason before even coming to posts in 2020. Another downside is that facebook_scraper takes a lot of time to scrape a page.

Comment: If that's the case, then, maybe scraping with Selenium would be a better choice.